# Invalid Argument js query

Tags: jquery

http://pittsburghwedding.whsites.net/

I am a novice and do not have any css or js experience.  I am creating my first wordpress site using Genesis and a child theme.

I get this error, but not on every page load.  It only pops up after I think the problem has been solved...

> Invalid Argument js query or Access is denied jquery

I don't know if this is an issue with my computer, internet provider or because once I noticed the errors I kept reloading the site until I could see it happen again and get some debugging information.

This is the debugging info for Access is denied.  I C&P everything because I don't know what is important.

Comment: http://www.pittsburghweddingphotographer.com/debug/debug.txt

Comment: can you be more specific of your error, like: "when I click on xxxx I see the error, and the error doesn't allow me to yyyy"

Comment: The access denied error stops the home page slide show from loading and the icon just spins. The jquery conflict error just throws the warning debug icon on the lower left hand side of the page.  But otherwise it doesn't seem to affect the site from what I can tell.   The errors never happen at the same time, and don't happen every time I refresh the home page.

Comment: FROM THE HOME PAGE CODE:'jquery.fancybox-css'     /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2'>     </ jquery.fancybox.js?ver=1.2.6'     fancy-box/jquery.easing.js?ver=1.3'      nextgen-gallery/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=2.88'     jQuery(document).ready(function($){ var select = $('a[href$=".bmp"],       a[href$=". jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#ngg-slideshow-4-5-1

Comment: Are you using a local copy? I see the slideshow, maybe it is a problem when you are designing it on a local copy, without a running webserver. I've tested in IE, FF, Chrome and seems to work fine.

Comment: The slideshow is a plugin that uploads to the server.  I click a button to add it to the page.  The (){ jQuery("#ngg-slideshow-4-5-1 was added by the theme designer for me because the slideshow was off center.

Comment: The W3 Total Cache Plugin creator said that the "first file is out of order."  I assume he means that 'jquery.fancybox-css' /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2' should not be first.  I am using his plugin with all options except minify. (It causes errors immediately because either the tmeme or its child minify already causing an error.)  He asked if I was using his plugin (I sent him the debugging log created by his plugin that has its name all over it.)  And he replied "Ok, then you're not using any W3TC features that can help/cause this issue, sorry."

Comment: I found another plugin that allows a Use jQuery noConflict mode. I am going to fresh the home page a million times and see if the error is still there.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict  this may be the answer.  I just don't know how to implement it.